# dd - unrecongnized operand of=/dev/sdc when trying to create a bootable USB

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I am trying to create a bootable USB. Currently on lsblk I have sdc -> sdc1, formatted to fat32.

I am trying now to save my iso with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/puppylinux.iso \ of=/dev/sdc bs=4M && sync status=progress
```

The error I am getting is:

```
dd: unrecognized operand ‘ of=/dev/sdc’
```

From all the searching I did, I can see that the of=...should be as I wrote it to be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Please remove the backslash before `of=...` 2. `status=...` will not work where you put it.  It should be before `&&` or not at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dd` command that you tried has an unnecessary `/` character after `if=/dev/puppylinux.iso` which should be removed. `sync` is a separate command, so it goes after the `&&` so that `sync` runs only if the first command ( `dd` ) ran.

The correct command is:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/puppylinux.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress && sync
```

Comment: +1; This will work, but using `dd` like this is risky, because `dd` has no final checkpoint, so it is easy to write to and overwrite the wrong drive. I would recommend **Ubuntu's Startup disk creator**, **Disks** (alias `gnome-disks`) or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: Startup Disk Creator is a great USB creator program which I prefer to use instead of `dd`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just wanted to fiddle a bit with the dd command. Thanks! 

Won't let me upvote the answer because of low reputation. :(